# Plotly js live update from online data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

I would like my Plotly graph to update automatically every 1 seconds by reading data from an online CSV file.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script>
      function read_data() {
        d3.csv(
          "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTkbRgvvBwM0tMheEziQC4ldtYoMVCgIek67Y5Lcjnu1WH0tTLLCzJPse-pL5OTR9U58Gk8VBD65L3u/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv",
          function (data) {
            processData(data);
          }
        );
      }

      function processData(allRows) {
        console.log(allRows);
        var x = [];
        var y = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
          row = allRows[i];
          x.push(row["x"]);
          y.push(row["y"]);
        }
        console.log("Y", y);
        return y;
      }

      Plotly.newPlot(graph, [
        {
          y: [1, 2, 3],
          mode: "lines",
          line: { color: "#80CAF6" },
        },
      ]);

      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        Plotly.restyle(
          graph,
          {
            y: [[read_data()]],
          },
          [0]
        );
      }, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Although the `y` data is printed in the console, the plot is not updated.

My script is based on these two tutorials:

- [Streaming in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/streaming/)
- [Read CSV Data from an Ajax Call in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/ajax-call/)

---

Additional question: is there a way to automatically update the graph each time the data is updated in the CSV document? That is, without having to loop over each second.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `read_data()` returns `undefined`. It also schedules `processData()` to run later, and that function returns some data, but it was called by the JavaScript runtime which ignores this returned value.

You could stick the `Plotly.restyle(...` code in a function that processData calls, or you could stick that code inside processData. See the code sample below.

However, there's another issue here (watch the code sample below fail). This file can't be loaded by a browser page right now. Google sheets links like
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTkbRgvvBwM0tMheEziQC4ldtYoMVCgIek67Y5Lcjnu1WH0tTLLCzJPse-pL5OTR9U58Gk8VBD65L3u/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv` [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550739/google-docs-pub-output-csv-no-longer-has-cors-headers) [longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587802/fetching-a-google-sheet-csv-file-yields-cors-error) [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568210/fetching-data-from-google-sheet-by-fetchurl-but-blocked-by-cors-policy) in the browser as of about 18 months ago.

You'll need to use another method to get your data into a web page (see linked questions above for some suggestions).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script>
      function read_data() {
        d3.csv(
          "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTkbRgvvBwM0tMheEziQC4ldtYoMVCgIek67Y5Lcjnu1WH0tTLLCzJPse-pL5OTR9U58Gk8VBD65L3u/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv",
          function (data) {
            processData(data);
          }
        );
      }

      function processData(allRows) {
        console.log(allRows);
        var x = [];
        var y = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
          row = allRows[i];
          x.push(row["x"]);
          y.push(row["y"]);
        }
        console.log("Y", y);
        
        Plotly.restyle(
          graph,
          {
            y: y,
          },
          [0]
        );
      }

      Plotly.newPlot(graph, [
        {
          y: [1, 2, 3],
          mode: "lines",
          line: { color: "#80CAF6" },
        },
      ]);

      var interval = setInterval(read_data, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code with both a local (`"data.csv"`) or a github hosted file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cnftstats/test/main/data.csv) and it still keeps ignoring the data. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: You'll need to serve CORS headers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Neither GitHub nor a file:// url will have these headers.